# Fixed width div breaks layout when scrollbars are visible

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stack a few divs vertically that have a "red" background which takes 100% of the page. Inside those divs i make 960px centered divs. What happens is very strange: if i resize my window to be less than 960px (for scrollbar to appear) - there is a gap at the right side of each stacked div. You can view live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/GLE7A/

Basic code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    * { padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; }
    .wmain { background: red; }
    .w960 { margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; }
</style>

<div class="wmain">
    <div class="w960">
    test
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wmain">
    <div class="w960">
    test
    </div>
</div>
```

**Solution is easy: just add min-width:960px; to the .wmain div to fix the problem**

**QUESTION**: why does this strange behaviour happen in the first place? Does a fixed-width child somehow escapes normal flow like absolutely positioned divs or smth.?

Thanks for your thoughts

Comment: so what you have tried first when you are getting the error?

Comment: Don't understand your question. The code in jsfiddle (and here) is not working properly and shows the problem. I've also provided a solution to this problem so i'm not interested in ways of fixing it. What i need to know is WHY this problem occurred in first place.

Comment: Your fiddle does not behave as you describe it should.  (Safari).

Comment: Weird, i've tested with firefox, opera, IE and when you scroll to the right - there is a white gap ...

Answer (score 1):

That occurs because you dont define any width for the wmain div that is what confusing the browsers.

Comment: I know that, i expected the parent would expand to the width of its child automatically, but i guess for some reason the block model does not work this way.